# "Fatal Error, cannot install GRUB on disk" while installing Ubuntu

Tags: permissions

I've installed Ubuntu numerous times via both VM and onto hard drives. Unfortunately it was a learning curve for me and I messed it up several times trying to designate partitions and running out of space too quick or otherwise.

The problem now. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 onto my laptop and I get all the way to the end and receive the error message (Fatal Error, cannot install GRUB on disk. Choose (select another disk, select do not install GRUB, Select cancel installation)

Each time I get here, I cannot install on ANY DISK, not just the SSD that I would really like to install upon. I have completely deleted, reformatted and otherwise destroyed to recreate several installations now. I want to start from scratch with an entire new installation and I would like to install on my brand new Western Dynamics SSD card (brand new as in a month old). I've read and tried many things but my specific question, given what has transpired up until this point, has not been addressed. What could I be missing?

```
~$ sudo parted -l

Model: ATA ST9500325ASG (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File System     Flags
 1      32.3Kb  500GB  500GB  primary  <nothing here>  lvm

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Model: ATA WDC WDS500G2BOB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File System     Flags
 1      1049Kb  500GB  500GB  primary  ext4

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Model: MXT-USB Storage Device (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 128GB
Sector Size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition table msdos
disk flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File System     Flags
 1      1049Kb  128GB  128G   primary  fat32           boot, lba
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95319/discussion-on-question-by-ziggy-fatal-error-cannot-install-grub-on-disk-while).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the GRUB installer was confused or if there was something screwy with the partition table on the OP's drive, but he was able to successfully complete the install by:

1. Physically removing the drive he did *not* want to install on from the system
2. Booting into the live envirnment in of the install media
3. Running this command to zero out the existing partition table/hanging EFI files/whatever that was on the first bit of his drive **WARNING: do NOT run this unless unless you know what you're doing, or else you might destroy data on another drive that you wanted to leave alone! While `/dev/sda` was the correct target disk in Ziggy's case, it may not be for you!**:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M count=32
   ```
4. Rebooting
5. Installing using "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"